# Sharepoint Designer opening current site in Sharepoint2007?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I made a test site after initial installation of Sharepoint 2007.
Is it possible for Designer to "hook into" Sharepoint and bring up the single page that is the site that I made?
Or, does the designer need to first make the page(s) then hook into the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do file|open site and type in URI